# Hide header from Tab page when user open page from left Menu [ionic 2]

Tags: menu, ionic2, ionic-tabs

I am creating application with Tabs and Menu. Here how it looks now.

### [image]

[image]

When I click on some page from the Menu it shows something like this.
[image]

I want to have tabs at the bottom but only header with title of the page clicked, not also header from the first page in Tabs page. Something like this

[image]

Here's the code for [Aktuelno page](https://github.com/janedzumerko/ionic2test/tree/master/src/pages/aktuelno), [App page](https://github.com/janedzumerko/ionic2test/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts) and [Tab page](https://github.com/janedzumerko/ionic2test/tree/master/src/pages/tabs)

Comment: You need the tabs at the bottom of every page?

Comment: @aminarghavani yes. I need that

Comment: I suggest you to use Toolbar (this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#toolbar)) instead of Tabs.